# How to mach all nodes that only have text and no children?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is my XML:

```
<foo>
  <a/>
  <b>Hello, world!</b>
  <c>Hey, <t>Friend!</t></c>
  <d><x/></d>
</foo>
```

I'm trying to create XSLT2 template to match only the nodes that contain plain text, like the nodes `b` and `t`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//*[not(*)]` selects all elements nodes not having child elements, if you also want to ensure the elements contain some non-whitespace text use `//*[not(*) and normalize-space()]`.